# Git: how can I have modified files and still checkout other branches?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch

I had to modify a few files in a project, but they are configuration files and I don't want to commit them (the config is just for my environment).
However, I'd still like to change branches, but when I use `git checkout` it says that my local changes would be overwritten. I don't know how to handle this.

I would like to have these changes, don't want to commit them (cause I then send pull requests on github and those changes would appear there, which is not what I want), but I'd still like to change branches. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

- When the files are `untracked`, put them in `.gitignore` so you never commit them.
- When the files are `tracked`, [stash](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing) them:

  ```
  git stash
  git checkout <other branch>
  git stash apply  #(This may or may not give some conflicts)
  ```

  When you no longer need these changes

  ```
  git stash drop
  ```

  Note that you can `apply` and `drop` in the same command with `git stash pop`, but this does not `drop` if there are conflicts, so its sometimes better to do them separately to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Untrack the files from Git and put the files in the .gitignore list.

git rm --cached filename

Answer (score 0):

If your modifications aren't supposed to ever leave your repo, use filters to apply and strip your local changes.  [Here's a worked single-file case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15936382/1290731).